# Shell or Bash script: Input a string line from a text file and search it recursively in a directory

Tags: shell, search, grep

I have a huge text file containing strings per line (properly edited with no empty lines or leading or trailing spaces) example input file

```
WeatherNation.us
AccuWeatherNOW.us
FashionTVUHD.fr
some upper case and lower case letters but without any blank.<country-tld>
so on
```

I want to search files containing these words (one by one) in a directory having lots of directories and xml files...the working command for single search is `grep -irwn "WeatherNation.us" /home/user/folder/` it displays files with paths and line numbers.

Search has to performed under /home/user/folder/ that has many folders say..fold1 fold2 fold3 etc. and each folder has many files say..1.xml 2.xml 3.xml etc. `grep -irwn "WeatherNation.us" /home/user/folder/` can returns output from many files.
Example entry in 2.xml inside fold3 and 5.xml inside fold2 also some search return only 1 entry or nothing in case string is not found.

I have tried to make a script as follows to automate all the searches

```
#!/bin/bash
 file="in.txt"
 while read -r line; do
      grep -irwn "$line" /home/user/folder/ >> out.txt
 done <$file
```

to store the result for each search in the out.txt file...but the script is not working & out.txt file is empty. Tried many other options `grep -irwn ""$line"" /home/user/folder`

I am using $line because `echo "$line"` inside the while do loop in the above script correctly displays all the inputs per line, but I don't know how to pass it to the grep command.
I am open to all other practical solutions, using `awk sed` etc.

Comment: grep can read from a file with `-f` (you may also want uppercase `-F` to disable regex)

Comment: `""$line""` means `<empty string>$line<empty string>`, exactly the same as just an unquoted `$line` on it's own - don't do that, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes.

Comment: You'll need to [edit] your question to define what a "word" means to you because in normal parlance and in the `\w` regexp escape sequence for matching word-constituent characters, word boundaries like `\<` and `\>`, etc. words don't contain `.`s. Also complete your [mcve] by adding an example of a file you'll be searching in and the output you expect given your 2 input files (file containing a list of "words", and a file to look for them in).

Comment: check your file `in.txt` does not have DOS line endings

Comment: _the working command for single search is grep -irwn_: Not true. With this command, a line containing `WeatherNation-us` would also match `WeatherNation.us`. You have to specify the option `-F` as well to avoid this pitfall.

Comment: @Ed Morton correct it should be called as a string  per line, these are all tvg-ids with only alphabets ending with  "." followed by <tlds> as mentioned ....no there are no 2 input files only 1 input i.e. in.txt  and it has all the strings per line. Every string has to be searched recursively within the folder ...basically -irwn switch to grep is working all right.

Comment: @user1934428 there is no "-" only "."

Comment: have you checked for DOS line endings yet?

Comment: @jhnc no I guess not, using gedit in ubuntu plus all entries in the file in.txt are displaying correctly when echoed inside the while do loop.

Comment: @jqurious plz provide an example. i am not an expert at shell and have spend lot of time on google to find a solution to the problem.

Comment: `grep -irwnF -f in.txt /home/user/folder > out.txt`

Comment: [As requested previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77129396/shell-or-bash-script-input-a-string-line-from-a-text-file-and-search-it-recursi?noredirect=1#comment135971295_77129396) - please complete your [mcve] by adding an example of a file you'll be searching in and the output you expect given your 2 input files (file containing a list of "words", and a file to look for them in).

Comment: Regarding DOS line endings - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it.

Comment: WHen you say [there is no "-" only "."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77129396/shell-or-bash-script-input-a-string-line-from-a-text-file-and-search-it-recursi?noredirect=1#comment135977705_77129396) - are you referring to the contents of the file that has the list of strings to search for or the contents of the file that needs to be searched for those strings? Providing a [mcve] so we have an idea what we're dealing with would be enormously helpful.

Comment: When you say [there are no 2 input files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77129396/shell-or-bash-script-input-a-string-line-from-a-text-file-and-search-it-recursi?noredirect=1#comment135977693_77129396) - the file containing the list of strings to search for is 1 input file, but every file that you need the script to search in for those strings is also an input file so we need to see an example of at least one of those plus the output given those 2 (or more) input files for us to have a [mcve].

Comment: @jhnc ..thanks for pointing it out it indeed had dos line endings after using gedit save as then selecting encoding utf-8 (it was already in utf-8) and linux option solved the problem.

Comment: Lesson learned: File saved as UTF-8 file in notepad++ does not necessarily mean that all the lines will not have DOS endings.

Comment: Don't expect people to click on links or download anything from any other site to be able to help you and if that link is to some input files that'd only be half what we'd need as we'd also need the expected output given that input and it's almost certainly more data than we need to look at to be able to understand your problem and may not cover all your possible use cases. Simply create and post a [mcve] in your question to make it as easy as possible for us to help you, see [ask]. The more effort you put into asking a good question the better your chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: The `-` was only an example. If the file has a pattern line `abc.ef`, and your file has a `abcdef` it would match as well. But well, you have to decide whether or not you want to catch such potential bugs.

Comment: @user1934428 I understand, I found the solution by testing it to all the possible inputs ...as pointed by jhnc the input file had dos line endings.

Answer (score 0):

The input file had dos line endings. The proper code tested with all possible inputs is same as what I tried initially with `$line` instead of `"$line"`.

```
grep -irwnF -f in.txt /home/user/folder > out.txt
```

partially works because it's skipping some outputs matched in files in various folders.